# Find Partial String in String Vector

Tags: c++

I have a vector of students, each element consists of ID and test answers.

ABCTFTFTF (ABC = ID, TFTFTF = Answers)

I am trying to retrieve just the block of TFTFTF's and compare them against a string that consists of the correct string of answers.

I understand it must be:

- students[i]
- create substring (start of answers = position 10, ends at position 30)
- compare substring
- act on comparison

But I am really struggling syntactically, could anyone point me in the right direction?

- **EDIT**

tried:

```
void getResults()
{

    string found;



 for(int i = 0; i < 150; i++)
    {
        found = students[i].find(answers);
        if(found == answers)
        {
            cout << "Student: " << i << "Passed" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Student: " << i << "Failed" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Personal project -- not homework

I am following this daily c++ projecs thread:

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/75558/

Mock Data:

```
OMXIZGWA TTFTFTFFTFTTFFFTTFTF
XKVNYUVZ F FTFFFFFT TFFTTTFFF
GGVDSSTQ TFFFTF FTTF TF  TFFT
XPYDXVIQ FFTTFT FTFT TFFTTTFT
XVFUMFZL TTFFTFFTFFTFF FFTFFT
```

(white char = no answer given)

*** EDIT ANSWER**

```
void getResults()
{

    string found;
    string foundSubString;

    for(int i = 0; i < 150; i++)
    {
        found = students[i];

        foundSubString = found.substr (9,20);


        if(foundSubString == answers)
        {
            cout << "Student: " << i << "Passed" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Student: " << i << "Failed" << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? Is this part of your job? If it is homework, you must absolutely tag the question as such.

Comment: Do you have a mock data file?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Answer (score 2):

Assuming:

- All IDs are unique
- Each ID is associated with one string of answers.

That sounds like a job for a dictionary. The C++ STL provides a handy `std::map`.

```
std::string answerKey = "TTFFTF"
std::map<std::string, std::string> studentAnswers;

studentAnswers["student1"] = "TFTTTF"; 
studentAnswers["student2"] = "FFTFTF"; 

// more students....
```

Now that you have defined the data you can define a comparison function. Say that you want to find the number of errors, you can define a prototype like this:

```
int compareAnswer(const std::string& correctAnswer, const std::string& valiantAttempt);
```

(*Note*: conveniently, this is actually exactly what the old-school C function from string.h, `strcmp` does)

Then use the function:

```
cout << "Student1 has " 
     << compareAnswer(answerKey, studentAnswers["student1"])
     << " errors" << endl;
```

Of course you would be using `for` loops and probably read the data from a file, etc., but I hope that gets you going in the right direction.

Comment: Hello, I edited my initial post to clear up some ambiguities I left for people. All ID's are unique.